# How do i get the number of grouped records in MYSQL

Tags: mysql

I want to group the records in a table based on user_id. The code below is working but i want to include the number of records in a each group.

```
SELECT u.user_id, 
        CONCAT(u.first_name, ' ', u.last_name) AS full_name, 
        u.salary,
        n.attendance_group AS month
FROM users AS u
    JOIN (
        SELECT user_id, FLOOR((attendance_count - 1) / 4) + 1 AS max_attendance_group
        FROM (
            SELECT user_id, COUNT(*) AS attendance_count
            FROM attendance
            WHERE is_present = ?
            GROUP BY user_id
        ) AS a
    ) AS b
ON u.user_id = b.user_id
CROSS JOIN (
   SELECT 1 AS attendance_group UNION ALL
   SELECT 2 UNION ALL
   SELECT 3 UNION ALL
   SELECT 4 UNION ALL
   SELECT 5
) AS n
WHERE n.attendance_group <= b.max_attendance_group
ORDER BY u.user_id, n.attendance_group;
```

current result

| id | name | month | salary |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | john doe | 1 | 20000 |
| 2 | jane doe | 2 | 20000 |

expected result

| id | name | month | salary | num |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | john doe | 1 | 20000 | 4 |
| 2 | jane doe | 2 | 20000 | 2 |

Comment: [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055). Provide sample data (#5) and desired output for it (#3).

Comment: you should think about restructuring your tables to be normalized (Backus-Naur-Form).
This means first to have no duplicate data in the table. In your example, all user data is duplicated over and over for each salary a user gets. put the salary to a second table and link the two tables with the user id.
after that, do a select of all users, join the salary table and you will get one row for each salary that exists, e.g. 4 rows for John and 2 for Jane. Then add sum(salary) and count(*) and put ID, name and month into GROUP BY clause.
Based on this you can finetune what you really need.